# Oops! Google Chrome could not find sahi.example.com

Tags: google-chrome, sahi

When I click on Google Chrome on the sahi dashboard it gives me the following error message:

"Oops! Google Chrome could not find sahi.example.com"

Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may need to configure the browser proxy. The following link might guide you for browser proxy configuration:

```
http://sahi.co.in/w/configure-browser-proxy
```

For Chrome:
To set up network connections for Sahi, follow these steps:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar (or click icon at the top right corner)
2. Select Settings
3. Click Show advanced settings link at the bottom of page
4. In the "Network" section, click Change proxy settings
5. Click LAN Settings under Connections tab
6. For Manual proxy server: Click Advanced -> Set “HTTP Proxy” to “localhost” and Set “Port” to “9999”

Comment: there is nothing about chrome

Answer (score 0):

Can you mention sahi version and java version? So to explain this, sahi.example.com is basically an alias for your localhost. Now this alias is found only when Sahi is running and your browser is using the Sahi proxy.This proxy is automatically set when you are launching a browser from Sahi. Make sure that proxy is set on chrome by manually testing it. If you are not able to see the proxy settings, set it manually and see if this problem is solved.

If you are using the Sahi Pro, you can ask the Sahi support team to resolve this if the proxy is not being set automatically